# Integrate Webservice into Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, api, xalan

**Edit:** Sorry guys, realised I have no idea when it comes to integrating Webservices in Java. Was  hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

**Original question**: *Hey everyone, I was wondering if you guys could point me in the right direction for this. I am required to find out how to inject data into an XML being created. I am using Java and the XALAN processor for my XML creation. The realtime data would either be coming form APIs or calls from a WebService.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that the 'real-time' element is of interest here.

Is the main issue that you're having difficulty manipulating XML via the standard DOM APIs ? If so, I would check out [JDom](http://www.jdom.org/), which is a Java API that will allow you to manipulate XML in a much easier/more intuitive fashion than the standard APIs.

Comment: Im not having too much of a problem manipulating the XML. I guess I should have worded my question better, so my issue can be split into two a) How to integrate webservice/api calling in my javacode.
b)How to transfer an unknown amount of data into the XML. The amount of data varies.

Comment: @Bilzac - why don't you edit your question to ask what you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention Xalan, maybe you are using XSLT. In that case, you can [pass parameters](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to the `Transformer` and [reference them by name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#top-level-variables) in the style sheet.

Comment: I figured I would do that, wasn't really sure how I would be able to implement that with a real-time webservice calls